# Print second last line from variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos, printf

```
VAR="1\n2\n3"
```

I'm trying to print out the second last line. One liner in bash!

I've gotten so far: `printf -- "$VAR" | head -2`

It however prints out too much.

I can do this with a file no problem: `tail -2 ~/file | head -1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost done this task by yourself. Try

```
VAR="1\n2\n3"; printf -- "$VAR"|tail -2|head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one pure bash way of doing this:

```
readarray -t arr < <(printf -- "$VAR") && echo "${arr[-2]}"
```

```
2
```

---

You may also use this `awk` as a single command:

```
VAR="1\n2\n3"
awk -F '\\\\n' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$VAR"
```

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `echo -e` for backslash interpretation and to translate `\n` to newlines and print the interested line number using `NR`.

```
$ echo -e "${VAR}" | awk 'NR==2'
2
```

With multiple lines and do, `tail` and `head` can be used to print any particular line number.

```
$ echo -e "$VAR" | tail -2 | head -1
2
```

or do a fancy `sed`, where you keep the previous line in the buffer-space (`x`) to print and keep deleting until the last line,

```
$ echo -e "$VAR" | sed 'x;$!d'
2
```

Comment: I was going to post this but `NR==2` means 2nd record not necessarily second last in the input.

Comment: @anubhava yes, you are right. I added a `tail | head` command. It's ugly :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe more efficient using a temporary variable and using expansions

```
var=$'1\n2\n3' ; tmpvar=${var%$'\n'*} ; echo "${tmpvar##*$'\n'}"
```